# Textbox Losing value under Jquery Modal Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using the script below for Modal Dialog box.I have a textbox and a button under dialog box div but when i click on button textbox value remains null why ? Can anyone help please

```
  //Everything is working fine but textboxes are losing their values on button click


 $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true });
         $("#dialog").dialog({ resizable: false });
         $("#dialog").dialog({
             buttons: {
                 //'Confirm': function () {
                 //    $("[id*=btn_Confirm_View]").click();
                 //},
                 'Cancel': function () {
                     $(this).dialog('close');
                 }
             }
         });

         $("#dialog").dialog({ draggable: false });
         $("#dialog").dialog({ closeOnEscape: false });

         $("#dialog").dialog({
             width: 'auto',
             autoOpen: false,
             show: {
                 effect: "blind",
                 duration: 1500
             },
             hide: {
                 effect: "scale",
                 duration: 300
             }

         });

         $("#dialog").dialog({
             close: function (event, ui) {

             }

         });
  //Everything is working fine but textboxes are losing their values on button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution ... :) 
Here is my Modified Code...

```
  //    $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true });
                 $("#dialog").dialog({ resizable: false });
                 $("#dialog").dialog({
                     buttons: {
                         //'Confirm': function () {
                         //    $("[id*=btn_Confirm_View]").click();
                         //},
                         'Cancel': function () {
                             $(this).dialog('close');
                         }
                     }
                 });

                 $("#dialog").dialog({ draggable: false });
                 $("#dialog").dialog({ closeOnEscape: false });

                 $("#dialog").dialog({
                     width: 'auto',
                     autoOpen: false,
                     show: {
                         effect: "blind",
                         duration: 1500
                     },
                     hide: {
                         effect: "scale",
                         duration: 300
                     }

                 });
//I Added these two lines and now they are working fine
                 $("#dialog").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
                 $("#dialog").dialog({
                     close: function (event, ui) {

                     }

                 });
```